# How to find similar data in two different columns from two tables in MIcrosoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

I am still new in using Microsoft Access and I have problem to use it. I am doing data mapping which compare 2 columns from 2 different tables. However, most of the data in both column is not exactly the same. Somehow, the data is slightly different between the tables.

**Example:**

Table A:

Column "name" : Atiqah bt Wahab

Column "email": atiqah@yahoo.com

**Table B:**

Column "account_name" : Atiqah Wahab

I want to compare column "name" in table A with column "account_name" in table B to get the email for data in column "account_name". 

I can find the matching data from column "name" and "account_name", but how can I find the 'almost-same' data from both table (As shown in the example above)?

Is there any ways I can do this? Really need help. Thank you

Comment: What if there are 10 John Smiths? and 3 of them have emails similar to jsmith1990@mail.com?

Comment: For this scenario, there is zero possibility that we have the same name or same email address. :)